# New Odoo installation

Tags: software-installation, odoo

I installed Odoo in localhost and after running this command:

```
./odoo-bin -c odoo-server.conf
```

and go to Chrome and say `localhost:8012` .

Results:

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
```

and in `./odoo-bin -c odoo-server.conf`

```
conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  role "pythondev" does not exist - - -
```

Comment: Can you check error in server log file  /var/log/odoo/odoo-server.log ?

Comment: This is a generic browser error message without any meaning. Please post the log entries in order to get information about the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Whoever runs odoo must also have an account that has permissions on postgresql.
In the error it shows it says that the user "pythondev" does not exist.
To solve:

```
sudo su - postgres -c "createuser -s pythondev" 2> /dev/null || true
```

Then set this user in odoo-server.conf